# I am still receiving the "timed out while waiting for program to exit" in my check50 (cs50 python course)

Tags: python, cs50

My output comes out correctly according to the manual check I did on my program, but when I run the check50 I get hit with this...

```
:) professor.py exists
:) Little Professor rejects level of 0
:) Little Professor rejects level of 4
:) Little Professor rejects level of "one"
:( Little Professor accepts valid level
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:| At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| At Level 2, Little Professor generates addition problems using 10–99
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| At Level 3, Little Professor generates addition problems using 100–999
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor generates 10 problems before exiting
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor displays number of problems correct
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor displays EEE when answer is incorrect
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| Little Professor shows solution after 3 incorrect attempts
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

it says "timed out while waiting for program to exit" after check50 inputs the correct valid level, but when I run the code myself it moves on to the next lines of code.

Here is my code if anyone can help me find the reason why it is timing out after inputting the correct level for the input.

```
import random


def main():
    get_level()









def get_level():
    r = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        lvl = input("Level: ")
        if lvl.isnumeric() == True:
            lvl = int(lvl)
        else:
            continue
        try:
            gen_number = generate_integer(lvl)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        break

    x = gen_number
    gen_number = generate_integer(lvl)
    y = gen_number
    right_answer = x + y
    while True:
        answer = input(f"{x} + {y} = ")
        answer = int(answer)
        if answer == right_answer:
            r += 1
            i = 0
            break
        else:
            if i >= 2:
                print("EEE")
                print(f"{x} + {y} = {right_answer}")
                i = 0
                break
            elif i <= 2:
                print("EEE")
                i += 1
                continue
    k = 0
    while True:
        gen_number = generate_integer(lvl)
        x = gen_number
        gen_number = generate_integer(lvl)
        y = gen_number
        right_answer = x + y
        while True:
            answer = input(f"{x} + {y} = ")
            answer = int(answer)
            if answer == right_answer:
                r += 1
                k += 1
                break
            else:
                if i >= 2:
                    print("EEE")
                    print(f"{x} + {y} = {right_answer}")
                    k += 1
                    break
                elif i <= 2:
                    print("EEE")
                    i += 1
                    continue

        if k >= 9:
            break
        else:
            i = 0
            continue
    print(f"Score: {r}")















def generate_integer(level):
    if level >= 4:
        raise ValueError

    if level <= 0:
        raise ValueError

    if level == 1:
        rand_number = random.randint(1,9)

    if level == 2:
        rand_number = random.randint(10,99)

    if level == 3:
        rand_number = random.randint(100,999)

    return rand_number




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/):

> Structure your program as follows, wherein `get_level` prompts (and, if need be, re-prompts) the user for a level and returns 1, 2, or 3, and `generate_integer` returns a randomly generated non-negative integer with level digits or raises a ValueError if level is not 1, 2, or 3:

The program does not return the level. It ultimately returns the `score`. `generate_integer` has the same flaw.

The program needs to be restructured so that

- `get_level` returns the level
- `generate_integer` returns the randomly generated integer
- the core logic is done in `main`